# Click through and on semi-transparent System.Windows.Controls.Image (PNG)

Tags: c#, image, click, png, transparent

I have a PNG file which is partially transparent.
I'd like to be able to click through the transparent areas and click on the non-transparent area's.

Eg. under a transparent area of this image is a button located.
When I click on this transparent area, the button should been clicked.

I started with the code below but I can't seem to get it work:

```
private void Image_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Image image = (Image)sender;
    Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(image);
    CroppedBitmap cb = new CroppedBitmap(image.Source as BitmapSource, new Int32Rect((int)mousePoint.X, (int)mousePoint.Y, 1, 1));                          

    byte[] pixels = new byte[4];
    cb.CopyPixels(pixels, 4, 0);

    if (pixels[3] != 0)
    {
       image.IsHitTestVisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
       image.IsHitTestVisible = false;
       e.Handled = true;
    }            
}
```

I also experimented with raising bubbled events, but still no luck.

any ideas ?